# Get Django object from modelfield ManytoMany

Tags: django

I would like to get your help in order to solve my issue.

I have a Django Application which is named Identity with an important model : `Societe`.

```
class Societe(models.Model):

    Nom = models.CharField(null= False, max_length=70, verbose_name='Nom de Société')
    ...
    #Some model fields
    ...
    user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name="User Access", default=" ")
```

This model is saved in my database as a table : **Identity_societe**

When I migrated my model, a new table **Identity_societe_user** which looks like is appeared :

[image]

[image]

This table gives an access to the `Societe` page for one or multiple users with `societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id, user=request.user)`

My issue is : I don't overcome to get objects from this table : **Identity_societe_user**.
I tried lot of things : `Societe_user`, `Societe_User`, `Societe.user`, ... but nothing up to now.

---

**EDIT :**

I update some things :

In my `model`, I have : `user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name="User Access", default=" ")`

In my `view`, I have `societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id, user=request.user)`

So How I can write something like this :

```
societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id, user=request.user and user.username=="Admin")
```

In order to allow Admin user and user which has a ForeignKey in `user_id` from the model Societe ?

Comment: Why do you want objects from that table? They're literally just links between User and Societe.

Comment: I need to pick up the `societe_id` for `user_id = 3` (it's an example). I would like to make this process because I need to redirect user to : `http://myapplication/Societe/ + str(societe_id)`

Comment: But this is a many-to-many relationship. There are **many** societe IDs for User 3. If you only want one, you should use a different relationship type, eg a ForeignKey.

Comment: All users have juste one societe IDs. Only the `user_id = 1` have the entire range `societe_id` (it's the admin user).

Comment: Then, as I say, use a ForeignKey from User to Societe instead.

Comment: I don't understand one thing, If I use ForeignKey, I couldn't not attribute a societe to one user and the admin user. Each user can connect to their own societe with `societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id, user=request.user)`. But I can't add admin user to see each societe page.

Comment: But why does that matter? The admin can see them all, there's no need for a specific relationship. Just check if the user is the admin, if so show everything, otherwise do the query for the specific one.

Comment: I changed my model to `model.ForeignKey`. I will update my question in order to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didn't understand very well your question but, in your view you could add a if statement like

```
if request.user.username == 'Admin': 
    ....
    return #all the societe page
else:
    societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id, user=request.user)
```

Or

```
if request.user.is_superuser: 
    ....
    return #all the societe page
else:
    societe = get_object_or_404(Societe, pk=id, user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'm really suck ... Maybe tired :/